# Underfull warning

Tags: bibliographies

I get following underfull warning:

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--5

but can't find the solution. Here is my code:

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{thebibliography}{110}

\bibitem{COP21} COP21, 2015. More details about the agreement. Available at: www.cop21.gouv.fr/en/more-details-about-the-agreement/ [Accessed January 29, 2016].

\bibitem{EWEA} Ho(EWEA), A. $\&$ Mbistrova(EWEA), A., 2015. The European Offshore Wind Industry: Key Trends and Statistics 1st Half 2015. , (January). Available at: http://www.ewea.org/fileadmin/files/library/publications/statistics/EWEA-European-Offshore-Statistics-2014.pdf.

\bibitem{EWEA2030} Corbetta, G., 2015. Wind energy scenarios for 2030. Ewea, (July), pp.1–8.

\bibitem{DEA} Miljøpåvirkninger fra havvindmøller  Energistyrelsen. Available at: www.ens.dk/undergrund-forsyning/vedvarende-energi/vindkraft-vindmoller/havvindmoller/miljopavirkninger [Accessed February 3, 2016].

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am not sure that this code produces the warning message

Comment: Use the `url` package and embed the URLs as `\url{www.cop21.gouv.fr/...}`

Comment: It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: are you sure it is from that code? 9999 times out of 10000 that warning is due to having `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, but there are no `\\ ` here. It's possible that it is your url (you should do as egreg says and use url package in any case, for those)

Comment: i added the url package and \url it works now :)